# How do i make the XR Ray Interactor face a different direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

so I'm relatively new to Unity XR, so I'm using the toolkit provided by unity. and I'm trying to get UI to work using the ray interactor but it is stuck facing upwards, I've tried changing the rotation via script and even parenting it to a empty game object with a set rotation, but nothing has worked. How would i go about fixing this so it faces forward
(forward being the direction the fingers are pointing)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLzGA.png)

sorry if this isn't enough info this is my first post ever so I'm not sure what all I need to put here